# Compare each name in one sheet with each string in another

Tags: vba, excel

There are two sheets named "Agents" and other one is "Owners" now the Agents sheets has about 37k rows in col "C" with Names like " CLARKE, DENISE JANE" All in one cell.

The other sheet "Owners" has very less about 1k rows of names in col "A" in format like this "Rafael" , "William" ,"Smith" ,etc all in different rows.

I am trying to compare each name in owners sheet with each string in agents sheet.

In this case. First Rafael will be compared with CLARKE then with DENISE then with JANE if match is found background color of Rafael

Now when I run this code it goes in maybe an infinite loop or something but the excel doesn't responds for a long time like 5 - 8 minutes it freezes. Even "Ctrl + Break" doesn't works I have to terminate it via task manager.  I tried finding any flaws in this code but I wasn't able to do so.

Can any one help ?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Duplica()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim i, j, m, d, k, l As Long
    Dim FinalRow, FinalRow1 As Long
    Dim ws, wr As Worksheet
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim Own
    Dim Ago

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = Sheets("Agents")
    Set wr = Sheets("Owners")

    FinalRow = ws.Range("C90000").End(xlUp).Row
    FinalRow1 = wr.Range("A90000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        l = 0
        pos = 0

        With ws
        str1 = .Cells(i, "C").Text
        str1 = Replace(str1, "&", " ")
        str1 = Replace(str1, ",", " ")
        Ago = Split(str1, " ")
        End With

        For d = 1 To FinalRow1
            With wr
            str2 = .Cells(d, "A").Text
            str2 = Replace(str2, "&", " ")
            str2 = Replace(str2, ",", " ")
            Own = Split(str2, " ")
            End With

            For m = LBound(Ago) To UBound(Ago)
                For j = LBound(Own) To UBound(Own)
                    If Len(Own(j)) > 0 And Len(Ago(m)) > 0 Then     'if not a empty string
                    pos = InStr(1, Ago(m), Own(j), vbTextCompare)    'Find the owners name in Agents name
                    If Own(j) = Ago(m) Then                           'If both are same
                    l = l + 1                                          'increment l
                    Else: End If
                    Else: End If

                    If l > 0 Or pos >= 1 Then
                    With wr
                    .Cells(d, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    End With
                    l = 0
                    pos = 0
                    Else: End If
                    l = 0
                    pos = 0

                Next j
            Next m
        Next d
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do a debug.print on finalRow? Also, you realize all but the last variable is declared as type variant? You have to do `dim ws as worksheet, wr as worksheet` for both to be type worksheet.

Comment: I assume it is just taking a long time due to your four nested for loops.  There is almost always better logic than having that many for loops.  It runs for me but I don't have the data that is on your worksheets so it is hard to know if that is causing an issue.

Comment: what are your values for `FinalRow`, `UBound(Ago)` and `UBound(Own)`? All 3 are used in triple nested loop which basically means the number of iterations = multiplication of all 3

Comment: @MatthewD you can have a look at the file if you need here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6nvnvdcrvdde0j/Macro.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: @Raugmor FinalRow is greater than 37k and Ubound(Ago) is less than 4 and Ubound(Own) is mostly equal to 1 for all the rows.

Comment: I have it. Let me put something together for you.

Comment: Actually you have 4 nested loops, looks like you are going through 100,000,000 iteration of it there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. It is a bit more straight forward.  It is still going to take a few minutes as this is a lot of data to process.

The find option of `LookAt:=xlPart` gives us the search of any part of the field.  Let me know if this works.  The only issue is we may have an owner named bob and a agent name of Jimbob.  That would be a hit.  We can change it to look at each name if that is an issue.

```
Sub Duplica()

    Dim wsAgents As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsOwners As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wsAgents = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Agents")
    Set wsOwners = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Owners")

    'Get the last row that has an owner name
    lastRow = wsOwners.Cells(wsOwners.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through the sheet with the owners
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= lastRow

        'Search for the owners name in the column on the agents sheet.
        Set Rng = wsAgents.Range("C:C").Find(What:=UCase(wsOwners.Range("A" & lRow).Value), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        'If we found the owner on the agent sheet color the owners name red.
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            wsOwners.Range("A" & lRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Debug.Print str(lRow)

    'Increment to the next row
    lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @Rohan K Fixed a bug and made a speed improvement.

Comment: I think it should be `If Not Rng Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: @MatthewD What kind of sorcery is this ? Thanks Man :)

Comment: @BrakNicku is correct. I thought it was the other based on the results.